# Opencv Filter Performance

Tags: performance, opencv, filter

I am trying to process a real time video which consists of frames with 2048*2000 resolution.
When i profile my code, i see that the bottleneck is the below code :

```
filter_gauss->apply(src, proc_img);

cv::filter2D(proc_img, frame_seq[0], -1, kernel[0]);
cv::filter2D(proc_img, frame_seq[1], -1, kernel[1]);
cv::filter2D(proc_img, frame_seq[2], -1, kernel[2]);
cv::filter2D(proc_img, frame_seq[3], -1, kernel[3]);

cv::threshold(frame_seq[0], frame_seq[0], threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
cv::threshold(frame_seq[1], frame_seq[1], threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
cv::threshold(frame_seq[2], frame_seq[2], threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
cv::threshold(frame_seq[3], frame_seq[3], threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

proc_img = frame_seq[0] | frame_seq[1] | frame_seq[2] | frame_seq[3];
```

Is there any possible ways to improve this part of code in terms of performance ?
The kernels used above are like these :

kernel[0]

```
-1, -1, 4, -1, -1
```

kernel[1]

```
-1, -1, 4, -1, -1
```

kernel[2]

```
-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 6 , 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1
```

kernel[3]

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 6 , 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

filter_gauss

```
cv::Mat gaussian_kernel = cv::getGaussianKernel(7, 5.0);    

cv::Ptr<cv::FilterEngine> filter_gauss = cv::createSeparableLinearFilter(CV_8UC1, CV_8UC1, gaussian_kernel, gaussian_kernel);
```

Comment: try to utilize your gpu http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_filtering.html

Comment: i have already tried using GPU, however, the results were not identical with the ones that i get from CPU.

Comment: you are processing HD so gpu utilization is important. did you try hard enough? also you can use DFT instead of convolution, i.e. take image dft and filter dfts and multiply, then inverse dft the result. but this optimization comes latter.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html?highlight=dft#gpu-dft here you go

Comment: kernel[0] and kernel[1] are identical, you can compute convolution once. But I suspect that one of them should be column-vector and other row-vector.